# Multiple jQuery Tooltips Interfering With Each Other

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tooltip

I use the following code to have different tooltips, but only 1 tooltip per element.
They work just fine, if I only use 1 of them. But all together like this, they don't work properly (show up in the wrong location, with the wrong class, etc)

```
    var options = {
        show: true,
        hide: false,
        position: {
            using: function(position, feedback){
                $(this).css(position);
                $(this).addClass(feedback.horizontal);
                $(this).addClass(feedback.vertical);
            }
        }
    }


    //¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬
    // Top
    //¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬
    options.position.my     = 'center bottom';
    options.position.at     = 'center top-' + space;
    options.tooltipClass    = 'vertical';
    //...
    $('.jui-tooltip-top').tooltip(options);

    //¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬
    // Left
    //¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬
    options.position.my     = 'right center';
    options.position.at     = 'left-' + space + ' center';
    options.tooltipClass    = 'horizontal';
    //...
    $('.jui-tooltip-left').tooltip(options);

    //¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬
    // Right
    //¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬
    options.position.my     = 'left center';
    options.position.at     = 'right-' + space + ' center';
    options.tooltipClass    = 'horizontal';
    //...
    $('.jui-tooltip-right').tooltip(options);

    //¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬
    // Bottom (Default)
    //¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬
    options.position.my     = 'center top';
    options.position.at     = 'center bottom+' + space;
    options.tooltipClass    = 'vertical';
    //...
    $('.jui-tooltip').tooltip(options);
```

HTML (examples)

```
<a href="#" title="Some title" class="jui-tooltip-left">...</a>
<a href="#" title="Some title" class="jui-tooltip">...</a>
<a href="#" title="Some title" class="jui-tooltip-top">...</a>
```

---

What I figured out by now, when using all together, only the last one (bottom) always works. With the others, I then does not matter whether I provide the options or not.

--

**How can I make them work all together?**

Comment: If you comment the last line `// $('.jui-tooltip').tooltip(options);` the other three work fine?

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos I added some HTML examples

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos If I comment the last line, it doesn't change anyting. But if I comment the last 3 blocks, then the first one works. Also, if I comment the first 3 blocks, then the last one works, etc.

Comment: Your code seems fine. You should be doing something else wrong. Check it out http://jsfiddle.net/7ey28yfz/

Answer (score 1):

try just marking all your tooltips with the `data-toggle="tooltip"` and then activating them all with one line of jquery.

```
$(function () {

    ...

    $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip(options);
});
```

To achieve different positions using this technique, use the `data-*` pattern on the elements that have the tooltips and specify the position that way.  I believe its `data-placement="center top"` or something like that.

```
<a data-placement="center top" data-toggle="tooltip" href="#" data-original-title="Tooltip on top center">Tooltip on top center</a>
```

This way you dont need a different set of options for every placement, you can set a default placement in your options, and then override on elements that need a custom placement.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try that! Do I need to use `data-toggle=tooltip` or can I also use an arbitrary CSS class for this one?

Comment: Where is this documented with the `data-placement` attribute? I cannot find it anywhere on http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: if you're using bootstrap 3, its documented here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

Comment: if you're using bootstrap 2.3.2, its documented here: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tooltips

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using bootstrap at all

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, by "cloning" the `options`. They were interfering with each other, even after initialization.

```
$('.jui-tooltip-top').tooltip($.extend(true, {}, options, {
    position: {
        my: 'right center',
        at: 'left-' + space + ' center'
    },
    tooltipClass: 'horizontal'
}));

// etc
```